# Do pages loaded by AJAX need html & head & body tags

Tags: html, ajax, tags

I have a web page that loads the content of tabs via AJAX.  Each tab is a separate html file.

Does each html file which is loaded by ajax need the full `<html><head><body>` etc structure and tags?  It seems to work fine with the outermost tag being `<div>` but I'm not sure this is proper

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are injecting html into a page it should not have those tags as the DOM tree would already have these nodes and if they were present, they would be stripped out anyway. The only reason for the pages you load via ajax to have those tags is if in some context those pages would be loaded on their own and not only through ajax.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just inserting the required html for your tabs via ajax, then you don't need extra tags, because they are already present, such as

```
<html>, <head>, <body>
```

But if you are rewriting whole document then you may also include them. As the *head* tag contains info such as *title, css files and required scripts*.